# Change project repository using git

Tags: git

I have a project I work on. Lets call it `foo`. This project is in repository in github called `foo repository`.

I want to switch the project to another repository called `better foo`. I don't want to delete the existing repository. I want to make another one so all my changes appear on the other repository and the current one stays as it is.

The reason is that I have to work on two projects. The one is small and the second one is something like an upgrade on the first one with some changes. What I want is to make the first one, leave it be and change the directory of the project so that when I make changes they will appear on the second repository while the first one stays the same.

Comment: Why do you want another repository? Sounds like a new `branch` is what you need?

Comment: Different clients. I don't want the one to know about the other. I am doing very similar projects and just want to reuse my code with one command on the console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can update the remote url to the new repository:

```
git remote set-url origin git://new.repo.url
```

This will leave your existing repository  and any changes made will reflect in the new repository.

Comment: I get `error: No such remote 'origin'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git remote add betterfoo better_foo_repo_address` for adding another **repo address** in your current project.

After this you can `fetch` `betterfoo` repo by `git fetch betterfoo`, and  switch project between **master** and **betterfoo** by `git checkout master` or `git checkout betterfoo`.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is to make the first one, leave it be and change the directory of the project so that when I make changes they will appear on the second repository while the first one stays the same.
>
> Different clients. I don't want the one to know about the other. I am doing very similar projects and just want to reuse my code with one command on the console line.

It is best to keep the codebase separated then: fork your repo on the server side (ie duplicate it)

Clone the second repo in a second local folder.

That way, the first folder is still referencing your original repo.